# Substite newlines with a string with awk

Tags: string, awk, newline, stdin, string-substitution

I need to parse stdin in the following way:

(1) all newlines characters must be substituted with `\n` (a literal `\` followed by `n`)

(2) nothing else should be performed except the previous

I chose `awk` to do it, and I would like an answer that uses `awk` if possible.

I came up with:

```
echo -ne "A\nB\nC" | awk '{a[NR]=$0;} END{for(i=1;i<NR;i++){printf "%s\\n",a[i];};printf "%s",a[NR];}'
```

But it looks cumbersome.

Is there a better / cleaner way?

Comment: `echo -ne "A\nB\nC" | sed -z 's/\n/\\n/g'`?

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n"}1'`?

Comment: @Cyrus The `sed` solution works, thanks. The `awk` one doesn't, as it adds a trailing `\n`.

Comment: `echo -ne "A\nB\nC"` outputs a string without a terminating newline which means it's not a valid text file and so YMMV with using any text processing tool on it.

Comment: @glennjackman no the last character of the string is `C`, not a new line

Comment: If you just want to create a string that is readable by any shell, you could just use `printf "%q"`. Example `printf "%q" "$(echo -ne "A\nB\nC")"`

Comment: @EdMorton I don't know whether there is some sort of standard for text files. I have read it is good practice for it to end with a newline, but I don't know whether that's coded somewhere. Anyway, that is the input we have. We can complain about it all we want: it's not going to change.

Comment: @kvantour I don't understand what you mean by "readable by any shell"

Comment: A string that can be passed on the command line interface (such as the `$'A\nB\nC'` or `$'A\r\bB'` or `$'A\tB'`) ( See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html )

Comment: @robertspierre the standard for text files is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_403 and for text lines (which a text file is made up of) is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206. The standards for text processing tools like awk, sed, grep, etc. all say some variation of "Input files shall be text files" (e.g. under INPUT FILES at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) so when you don't have that then YMMV.

Comment: Although you have data that doesn't end in a terminating newline and so isn't a valid text file, that doesn't mean that's what you need to use as input to a text processing tool, you could add a newline, e.g. `{ cat file; printf '\n'; } | awk '...'` or various other approaches. In practice I expect most versions of awk and sed to be able to handle no terminating newline (not sure about grep) in some fashion but other tools will surprise you.

Comment: @Cyrus : if you really want `awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\\n"}1'` then might as well ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: `awk 'ORS = "\\n"'` or `awk 7 ORS='\\n'`

Comment: @robertspierre : the really really amateur-hour workaround I have in my own codes for this is something like :  `gcat - <( gprintf %s\\n '|_fakeEOFfake_|' )` - using `cat` to append an artificial `"EOF"-ish` text string, regardless of actual ending, and have the `awk` code properly remove its effects afterwards. i know i know - bad coding style and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
echo -ne "A\nB\nC" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\n"; OFS="\\n"; RS=ORS=""} {$1=$1}1'
```

Output:

```
A\nB\nC
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: That would fail if the input contained a blank line. Try `echo -ne "A\nB\n\nC" | ...`.

Answer (score 2):

- Handling malformed files (ie. that don't end with the record separator) with `awk` is tricky.
- `sed -z` is GNU specific, and has the side effect of slurping the whole (text) file into RAM (that might be an issue for huge files)

Thus, for a robust and reasonably portable solution I would use `perl`:

```bash
perl -pe 's/\n/\\n/'
```

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way

```
echo -ne "A\nB\nC" | awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,RT?"\\n":""}'
```

gives output

```
A\nB\nC
```

*(without trailing newline)*

Explanation: I do create string to be output based on current line context (`$0`) and backslash followed by `n` or empty string depending on `RT` which is row terminator for current line. `RT` value is newline for all but last lines and empty string for last line, therefore when used in boolean context it is true for all but last line. I used so-called ternary operator here condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ echo -ne "A\nB\n\nC" | awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= -F'\n' -v OFS='\\n' '{$1=$1} 1'
A\nB\n\nC$
```

Answer (score -1):

this should solve the blank line in between problem :

```
gecho -ne "A\nB\n\nC" |
```

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk 'BEGIN {  RS = "^$" ; FS = "\n" 
>                     ORS =  "" ; OFS = "\\n" } NF = NF' | gcat -b
> ```

```
     1  A\nB\n\nC%
```

a `gawk`-specific way via `RT` :

```
 gawk 'BEGIN { _ = ""; ORS =__= "\\n" } (ORS = RT ? __ : _)^_'
```